# IntelliJ IDEA not supporting Lambda?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, intellij-14

I'm working with this tutorial which uses lambda expressions.

[Spring Boot - Bookmarks](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

But IntelliJ says always: `cannot resolve method(<lambda expression>)`.

What do I have to check?

```
this.accountRepository.findByUsername(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(userId));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your IntelliJ or your project is not setup to use Java 8.

1. Open **Project Structure**
2. Look into **Project Settings | Project**, the value of **Project SDK** should be 1.8
3. Look into **Platform Settings | SDK**, there should be 1.8 listed

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: it is: project sdk 1.8 & sdk default 8

Comment: Try these: 1. Retype the example, make sure you entered it correctly; 2. **File / Invalidate Caches, Restart...**; 3. Reimport project; 4. Edit into your question the code snipped where the error is reported

Comment: @rala - also check Modules - Dependencies - Module SDK

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the "Project language level" to "8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.". You can find this option in "Project Settings" -> "Project"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above look into you pom.xml file. Source and target should be 1.8 or higher. e.g.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Java 17, got the same error, the solution for me was to specify the entity when declaring as Optional, like this:

```
Optional<User> findUserById(Long userId);
```

Because you want to receive a certain type, but also can be null or undefined.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).